# FileNotFoundException in android file picker

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, filechooser

I want to upload the file from mobile storage(both internal and external storage) to the server.By using a file chooser I got `FileNotFoundException`. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
public void openFileSystem(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload."), SELECT_FILE);
}
```

Here is my `onActivityResult()` and `getPath()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri path = data.getData();
        String url = data.getData().getPath();
        File file = new File(url);
        int size = (int) file.length();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            buf.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null)
        {
            int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

The error log:

```
05-07 06:41:03.087: W/System.err(2195): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/2: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-07 06:41:03.097: W/System.err(2195):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
05-07 06:41:03.097: W/System.err(2195):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
05-07 06:41:03.097: W/System.err(2195):     at com.gems.ComposeBulletin.onActivityResult(ComposeBulletin.java:121)
05-07 06:41:03.117: W/System.err(2195):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
05-07 06:41:03.117: W/System.err(2195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
05-07 06:41:03.127: W/System.err(2195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
05-07 06:41:03.137: W/System.err(2195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-07 06:41:03.137: W/System.err(2195):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
05-07 06:41:03.137: W/System.err(2195):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 06:41:03.157: W/System.err(2195):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 06:41:03.157: W/System.err(2195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-07 06:41:03.167: W/System.err(2195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 06:41:03.167: W/System.err(2195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 06:41:03.177: W/System.err(2195):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-07 06:41:03.187: W/System.err(2195):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-07 06:41:03.187: W/System.err(2195):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 06:41:03.197: W/System.err(2195): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-07 06:41:03.217: W/System.err(2195):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-07 06:41:03.217: W/System.err(2195):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-07 06:41:03.227: W/System.err(2195):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
```

So my motto is to choose any file(`image`, `pdf` ,`doc`) from internal storage or external storage and upload it on the server. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Post the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Post the logcat and have a look in it as it tells you exactly which staement causes the NullPointerException. Please tell us what code is on that line. And which pointer is null.

Comment: The size of the file gives 0 but i get the path of the file. So can't figure out why this is happening. .

Comment: did you set the correct `<uses-permission>` for reading that file?

Comment: It gives the FileNotFoundException in the FileInputStream

Comment: @SebastianWalla I have specified `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: `both internal and external storage)`. If you -as it looks- are using an external file chooser that chooser cannot pick files in the internal storage of your app.

Comment: @greenapps in the current state i am unable to access files from external storage aswell.

Comment: I know that already. But now i was talking about your file chooser who has no access to your internal memory. That's somenthing different. You are not going to tell about the used file choosers?

Answer (score 3):

That is not reliable with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, as there is no requirement that the `Uri` get back point to a file that you can access. The file might be on internal storage of an app, or on removable media, or even in the cloud somewhere. For what feels like the *sixth* time this week and definitely the second within the past ten minutes... [a `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

Use the `Uri` as designed, via methods on `ContentResolver` like `openInputStream()` and `getType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 Browse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.browsehoro);
    Browse.setOnClickListener(this); 

 public void onClick(View v)
{

    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.browsehoro:
        img.setEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Horoscope.this, FilePickerHoroscope.class);            
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);
        break;
    }


}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       /* if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedFile = getPath(selectedImageUri);

 //                Print imagepath in textview here
            filePath.setText(selectedFile);
            System.out.println(requestCode);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedFile);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);


        }*/


        switch(requestCode) 
        {

        case REQUEST_PICK_FILE:

            if(data.hasExtra(FilePickerHoroscope.EXTRA_FILE_PATH))
             {
                selectedFile = new String
                        (data.getStringExtra(FilePickerHoroscope.EXTRA_FILE_PATH));
                filePath.setText(selectedFile.toString());  
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String url = data.getData().getPath();
File file = new File(url);
```

The String url does contain a content provider path. In this case as you can see in the logcat `/document/2`. The `File` class cannot handle such content provider paths.

You first have to convert that path to a real file system path.

Google for 'getRealPathFromUri'.

Comment: `getRealPathFromUri()` (and its descendants) was written by a drooling idiot. It makes invalid assumptions about Android content. Those assumptions were unnecessary in the beginning but happened to work, and so this pattern got propagated. However, those assumptions are flat-out wrong now, and apps that use `getRealPathFromUri()`-style techniques break when using other apps that *do* play by the rules and use supported approaches like `FileProvider` for sharing content. Please stop promoting this technique.

Comment: Pretty harsh. getRealPathFromUri can return null we know so nothing has to break. The technique to get 'the real path' (.DATA) is the same as one would use to get .DISPLAY_NAME and .SIZE. So why would it be that wrong? Of course i know that the uri way is the way to go. But if one uses a file picker it's not a bad idea wanting to know the path of the file on the file system.

Comment: "The technique to get 'the real path' (.DATA) is the same as one would use to get .DISPLAY_NAME and .SIZE" -- `DISPLAY_NAME` and `SIZE` are part of the `OpenableColumns` contract. `DATA` is not. "So why would it be that wrong?" -- first, not every respondent of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is `MediaStore`. If the users choose an activity for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` that is not backed by `MediaStore` (e.g., Dropbox, Google Drive), then there is no filesystem path for the `Uri`.

Comment: Second, not every file on the filesystem that might be visible to `MediaStore` is accessible by apps. Removable media is a classic example: while the `MediaStore` itself can access all of removable media, apps cannot, particularly on Android 4.4+. "But if one uses a file picker" -- `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not a "file picker".